# Series convergence issues

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to show that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n}$$

is $C^1$ on ($1,\infty)$

To do so, I want to show uniform convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1+x^n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{-nx^{n-1}}{(1+x^n)^2}$

but I don't know how to do so

Comment: Can you show normal convergence on $(\alpha,\infty)$, for any $\alpha > 1$?

Comment: For normal convergence I need the series $\sum \sup | \frac{-nx^{n-1}}{(1+x^n)^2}|$ to converge, do I ? Then it would imply uniform convergence on $(\alpha,\infty)$.

Comment: Yes, indeed. If I'm not (too) mistaken, the function $f_n\colon x\mapsto n\frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x^n)^2}$ will be decreasing on $[\alpha,\infty)$, so that the sup is $\frac{n\alpha^{n-1}}{(1+\alpha^n)^2}\sim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\alpha^{n-1}}$.

Comment: Ok, is the sup mandatory, or any $u_n > |f_n|$ works ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. For normal convergence, you need $\sum \sup \lvert f_n \rvert$ to converge; if you get $\sum u_n$ to converge with $u_n \geq \sup \lvert f_n \rvert$, it does imply it as well, but is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes it is (sometimes it's easier to find $u_n$ than the sup). Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

First the given series is convergent on the interval $(1,+\infty)$. In fact by comparison we have

$$\frac1{1+x^n}\sim_\infty x^{-n}$$
and the geometric series $\sum x^{-n}$ is convergent.

Second for all $n\ge0$ the function $f_n:x\mapsto \frac1{1+x^n}$ is $\mathscr C^1$ on $(1,+\infty)$ and its drivative as you wrote is

$$f'_n(x)=-\frac{nx^{n-1}}{(1+x^n)^2}$$
Finally  the series $\sum f'_n$ is uniformly convergent on every interval $[a,\infty)$ where $a>1$. In fact
$$||f'_n||_\infty\le n a^{-(n+1)}=_\infty o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$
hence the series $\sum ||f'_n||_\infty$ is convergent. We deduce the desired result from the three last points.